# Translation of the kagura song

Tags: meaning, translation

> おおおお…
> 天地に き揺らかすは
> さゆらかす
> 神わがも
> 神こそは　きねきこう
> き揺らならば……

This is dedication to the god Gozu Tennou from the video game Shin Megami Tensei: Nocturne Maniacs.

It's almost the same as the first line of one of the kagura songs - [https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/阿知女作法](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%98%BF%E7%9F%A5%E5%A5%B3%E4%BD%9C%E6%B3%95)

There's a lot I can't understand:

1. Why there is き and さ before ゆらかす?
2. What is 神わがも? Is it 神我 (divine self) + も to emphasize?
3. What is きねきこう? According to wiki きね is probably the same as 巫女 (shrine maiden) and I suppose きこう is volitional form of 聞く. But who's the object of the action, is it "Hear the shrine maiden" or "Hear it, shrine maiden"?
4. What is the meaning of the whole line?

Comment: If you read the article, it actually says many parts of the song are unintelligible...

Comment: So other unknown words except for those listed in the wiki are totally obscure?

Comment: You can guess in many ways, but you can only guess. Note that mystic incantations are often word salads from the beginning.